# Django Tastypie: reverse url with "spaces". How?

Tags: python, django, url, reverse, tastypie

It's driving me crazy:

- I've got a Tastypie custom resource (not ModelResource).
- I need to allow "spaces" (%20 code) for the "primary key". For
  example:

  `localhost:8000/api/v1/collections/i%20am%20a%20space/`
- Adding a regex with "\s" works for `GET (obj_get)`, `PUT (obj_update)`
  and `DELETE (obj_delete)`

  ```
  def override_urls(self):
  return [url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<name>[\w\d\s_.-]+)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail")]
  ```
- The problem is with `obj_get_list`: when returning the object list,
  the parameter `resource_uri` is empty if a space is present. The code
  fails in the function `reverse` (django.core.urlresolvers) with a
  `NoReverseMatch` exception.

I tried even to overwrite the base_urls from tastypie but it didn't work and I am really lost right now. Maybe it's a noob question but take into account that I started with django and python about 1 month ago: I am a noob :-P

Comment: Solved: I'm a supernoob :-P just changed the "name" for "pk" in the regex expression: ^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<name>[\w\d\s_.-]+)/$

Comment: maybe you shall just put your solution in the answer, so that it won't appear in the unaswered section.

Answer (score 0):

just changed the "name" for "pk" in the regex expression:

```
^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<name>[\w\d\s_.-]+)/$
```